# How can I get the owner of every file in a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I need to check if root is the owner of every file in a particular directory.  I can do

```
stat --format=%u /directory/name/here
```

to get the owner of the directory itself, but not the files in it.

My other idea was to do

```
ls -lL | grep "^-\|^d" | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

but that doesn't work if the last byte in the permissions is a space and not a '.'.

This is also CentOS if that matters.

Comment: What is the exact output you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking two different questions.

> I need to check if root is the owner of every file in a particular directory

To find any files that are *not* owned by root, you can do:

```
find /yourdir ! -user root
```

If it returns any filenames at all, then root is not the owner of every file in the particular directory.

> How can I get the owner of every file in a directory in Linux?

To print every file in the directory with username:

```
find /yourdir -printf '%u %p\n'
```

And if the final step would be to `chown` the files not owned by root, you can simply do `chown -R root /yourdir`, since there's no harm in chowning root's files to root.

Comment: Is it possible to check if there are any files not owned by any of several usernames?  Something like find /yourdir ! -user (root, user1, user2, user3) | wc -l  ?

Comment: You can use `-a` for "and". `find yourdir ! -user root -a ! -user foo -a ! -user bar` (`-a` is actually optional here, but included for illustration)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `find`:

```
find /tmp -type f -printf '%u\n' | sort -u
lightdm
root
tiago
```

If you need UID in numeric form, like using `stat`:

```
find /tmp -type f -printf '%U\n' | sort -u
0
1000
104
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 find /your/dir/ -type f -exec stat --format='%u %n' '{}' \;
```

I added `%n` to display the file name.

Read [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more info about `find` .... You may want `-max_depth 1` to avoid going deeply in `/your/dir/`

Comment: What about using -execdir instead?  The man page says it is more secure.  I don't actually know how though.

Comment: If you are going to use find you should probably just use `-printf %u\\n` and avoid the need for `-exec` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
for F in /directory/*; do stat --format='%u' "$F"; done
```

And optionally add `dotglob` option to match files beginning with . as well:

```
shopt -s dotglob
for F in /directory/*; do stat --format='%u' "$F"; done
```

***** `--format` is equivalent to `-c`.

Comment: @michaelAdam Updated answer with respect to it.